# How to update Kubernetes secrets for all namespaces

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, gitlab-ci

I am using docker and kubernetes on Google Cloud Platform, with the Kubernetes Engine.
I have secrets configurated in a app.yaml file like so :

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: app
  namespace: $CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG
  labels:
    app: app
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: app
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: app
        image: gcr.io/engagement-org/app:$CI_COMMIT_SHA
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9000
        env:
        - name: MAILJET_APIKEY_PUBLIC
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: mailjet
              key: apikey_public
        - name: MAILJET_APIKEY_PRIVATE
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: mailjet
              key: apikey_private
```

Each time I push on a new branch, a new namespace is created through a deploy in my gitlab-ci file. Secrets are created like so :

```
 - kubectl create secret generic mailjet --namespace=$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG --from-literal=apikey_public=$MAILJET_APIKEY_PUBLIC --from-literal=apikey_private=$MAILJET_APIKEY_PRIVATE || echo 'Secret already exist';
```

Now, I have updated my mailjet api keys and want to make the change to all namespaces.
I can edit the secret on each namespace by getting a shell on the pods and running `kubectl edit secret mailjet --namespace=<namespace_name>`

What I want is to send the new secret values to the new pods that will be created in the future. When I deploy a new one, it still uses the old values.

From what I understand, the gitlab-ci file uses the app.yaml file to replace the environment variables with values. But I don't understand where app.yaml finds the original values.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: This seems to be about how GitLab CI does things. Normally you wouldn't create a new namespace for every commit, that doesn't sound like a great practice (but you can, nothing is preventing you from doing that). There's no kubernetes-native way of updating a resource in multiple namespaces simultaneously. Namespaces are meant to be separate so you can’t mess up multiple of them at the same time.

Comment: Ok, I understand. So I won't update all of my namespaces together. But what about the namespaces that aren't created yet? When I create the secret for them, can I use different values?

Comment: I found the answer, they were configurated in Gitlab itself.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In general, Kubernetes namespaces are designed to provide isolation for components running inside them. For this reason, the Kubernetes API is not really designed to perform update operations across namespaces, or make secrets usable across namespaces.

That being said, there are a few things to solve this issue.

#### 1. Use a single namespace & Helm releases instead of separate namespaces

From the looks of it, you are using Gitlab CI to deploy individual branches to review environments (presumably using Gitlab's [Review App](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/review_apps/) feature?). The same outcome can be achieved by deploying all Review Apps into the same namespace, and using [Helm](https://helm.sh/) to manage multiple deployments ("releases" in Helm-speak) of the same application within a single namespace.

Within the `gitlab-ci.yml`, creating a Helm release for a new branch might look similar to this:

```
script:
- helm upgrade --namespace default --install review-$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG ./path/to/chart
```

Of course, this requires that you have defined a [Helm chart](https://docs.helm.sh/developing_charts/#charts) for your application (which, in essence is just a set of YAML templates with a set of default variables that can then be overridden for individual releases). Refer to the documentation (linked above) for more information on creating Helm charts.

#### 2. Keep secrets in sync across namespaces

We have had a similar issue a while ago and resorted to writing a custom Kubernetes controller that keeps secrets in sync across namespaces. It's open source and you can [find it on GitHub](https://github.com/mittwald/kubernetes-replicator) (use with caution, though). It is based on annotations and provides unidirectional propagation of changes from a single, authoritative parent secret:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: mailjet
  namespace: some-kubernetes-namespace
  annotations:
    replicator.v1.mittwald.de/replicate-from: default/mailjet
```

With the secret replicator deployed in your cluster, using this annotation will propagate all changes made to the `mailjet` secret in the `default` namespace to all secrets in any namespaced annotated like show above.

Comment: Thank you so much! Indeed, that is what I am doing with gitlab, and I will definitely look into these two solutions if they are better designed for the project.
I just have a quick follow-up question : from what I understand of your answer, there is no way to update all existing namespaces in a single operation.
However, can I change the variables Kubernetes is reading from so that all new namespaces from now on will use these? Are the original variable values stored in the "default" namespace?

Comment: I just found where the original values were stored : it was in my gitlab project, in settings => CI/CD => Secret Variables.

Answer (score 1):

Now there is a way to share or sync secret across namespaces and its by using the ClusterSecret operator:

https://github.com/zakkg3/ClusterSecret